# MVC Dropdown list not showing selected value using ViewBag

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewbag

I have filled the ViewBag.BankNames using Banks table as

```
ViewBag.BankNames = new SelectList(db.Banks, "BankId", "BankName", applicationSettings.BankId);
```

where applicationSettings.BankdId is having the value which I need to show as the selected value in dropdown, then passed the applicationSetting model object to view.

In my View I have used that ViewBag like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BankId, ViewBag.BankNames as SelectList, "Select Bank", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It will show me the dropdown list with all values of Bank names but the selected value is **Select Bank** and not the value which I set as selected value in ViewBag?

Answer (score 1):

Can you assign applicationSettings.BankId to BankId of model property and check..

you are binding @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BankId, ViewBag.BankNames as SelectList, "Select Bank", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) but in model.BankId is zero..

Assign Model.BankId = applicationSettings.BankId before returning it to view

```
In Controller

public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var banks = new List<Banks>()
            {
                new Banks()
                {
                    BankId =1,
                    BankName = "Bank 1"
                },

                new Banks()
                {
                    BankId =2,
                    BankName = "Bank 2"
                }
            };


            var list = new SelectList(banks, "BankId", "BankName");
            

            ViewBag.Banks = list;

            var modelBanks= new Banks();
            modelBanks.BankId = 2;

            return View(modelBanks);
        }
```

```
In View
@model Banks
@using WebApplication3.Models
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BankId, ViewBag.Banks as SelectList,"Select Bank")
```